# EPPlus worksheet always throws Exception at first attempt, then works at the second attempt

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, epplus

This snippet of code is from a larger function in an MVC controller where a form with a file is posted. The inputStream comes from the uploaded file:

```
var excelFile = new ExcelPackage(inputStream.BaseStream);
ExcelWorksheet worksheet;
try
{
    worksheet = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets["Products"];
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // Second time always works?
    worksheet = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets["Products"];
}
```

It *always* crashes when trying it at first and then it will work the second time. The exception I get is "An item with the same key has already been added.". The second attempt never fails.

Sure this is working code, but people might be tempted to poke fun at me for checking this in ;)

Version:

```
EPPlus.dll, v3.1.3.0
```

Comment: Thats an interesting one.  What if you did `inputStream.BaseStream.Flush()` and/or `inputStream.BaseStream.Position = 0`?

Comment: @Ernie: I've just tried it, it's the same

Comment: Please post the exception, and which version of the library you're using.

Comment: I added the version, do you need the whole stack of the error?

Comment: Alot has changed since version 3.  Might try version 4 to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I am getting this error in EPPlus 4.1.1. some part of stack trace is:
_[ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.]
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) +52
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) +12524358
OfficeOpenXml.Table.ExcelTableCollection..ctor(ExcelWorksheet ws) +331
OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.get_Tables() +80
OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook.ReadAllTables() +137
OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.get_Tables() +52
_

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem today. Very frustrating! I even looked into the source code of EPPlus to see what was going on, but it didn't really help.

My problem ended up being because the spreadsheet that EPPlus was reading was an .xlsx spreadsheet created by LibreOffice Calc, not by Microsoft Excel. Even though LibreOffice was exporting in the right format, and the spreadsheet could be opened in Excel, something was missing that EPPlus was expecting. As soon as I saved the spreadsheet from Excel instead of LibreOffice, no issues.

Comment: This was my issue today.  Re-saved the excel document, as an actual excel, and it worked "magically".

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with 4.5.3.2 version.
Just overcome by using the second call time.

Comment: Wow it's crazy this still happens! I don't even program .Net anymore!